# C# USB HidDevice Class

Tags: c#, hid

I have tried to use the sample of code from microsoft documentation in order to connect to a hid device: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice?view=winrt-22000

I have made a C# console application and also a UWP application, but with both of them I encounter the same behaviour.
Even though my device is found there:

```
        string selector = 
            HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vendorId, productId);
        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
```

I cannot open it for read/write and this line of code manages to close my application with no errors:

```
HidDevice device = 
                    await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(devices.ElementAt(0).Id,
                    FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
```

Has anyone experienced this and may have a solution to it?
Thank you!

Comment: So did you read the bottom of the page? - "*Apps that use this class to access a HID device must include specific DeviceCapability data in the Capabilities node of its manifest*" - When you did this, did it help?

Comment: Yes, I have added Device Capability to app.manifest file and no success.